# Need help to understand why this statement is written this way. While guess != correct and guess != " "

Tags: python-3.x, logic, operator-keyword

i'm trying to understand there statement below 
 while guess != correct and guess != " ": 
 i tried running with ..... while guess != correct:
 program still runs fine and has no difference. I hope someone can explain why the part guess != " " 
 is needed there. Thank you

```
import random 
WORDS = ("difficult","python","dark","smile") 
word = random.choice(WORDS) 
correct = word 
jumble = " " 

while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]

print(
    '''
        Welcome to Word Jumble!
        Unscramble the letters to make a word.
        (Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)
        '''
)
print("The jumble is:", jumble)
guess = input("what is your answer?")

    while guess != correct and guess != " ":

    print("sorry wrong guess")
    guess = input("guess again:\n")

    if guess == correct:
    print("you are right!")

print("thanks for playing")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Perhaps so there is a way out for the user if they give up?

Comment: Also it looks like the indentation is wrong for the next 2 lines. I would expect them to be part of the while statement. Indentation is critical in python!

Comment: thanks Gem. yes you are right on the indentation. on the part guess != " ": .... what do you think will/can added to allow user to have a way out should they give up? thank you for sharing as I'm relatively new to programming, trying to learn here.

Comment: Perhaps they just press return or press space and return.